# Google Chrome CSS incorrect position

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a login form that is perfectly correct in all other browsers. However, sometimes it gets twisted in Google Chrome. Sometimes it shows up correctly - but almost always it incorrect.

[image: Google Chrome print of the problem.]

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}

body {
    background: #E8E8E8;
}

#logo {
    width: 244px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 0;
    background: url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat;
}

#loginbox {
    width: 330px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid  #6A6A6A;
    background: url(../img/bg-top-login.png) repeat-x;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    margin-top: 80px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #828282;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #828282;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #828282;
}
```

Comment: can you post also your html code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Post your html markup

Comment: jsfiddle @AndréFigueiredo http://jsfiddle.net/n23fh/

Comment: @bdrx http://jsfiddle.net/n23fh/

Comment: just an observation time the position is regular, equal firefox like a bug google chrome, however sometimes it gets in the wrong place, still could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should use these images as css background:

```
<p class="textlogin">Usuario</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Digite Seu Nome de úsuario" name="usuario" />
<div class="ico"><i class="usuario"></i></div>

<p class="textlogin">senha</p>
<input type="password" placeholder="Digite a senha da conta" name="senha" />
<div class="ico"><i class="senha"></i></div>
```

CSS:

```
.ico i {
     display: block;
       width:20px;
       height:20px;
       margin-top:2px;
       margin-left:4px;
}
.ico i.usuario {
    background-image: url('http://s12.postimg.org/ad8v4wvex/user.png');
}
.ico i.senha {
    background-image: url('http://s13.postimg.org/iexiozs83/loked.png');
}
```

Your CSS has an incorrect property `.ico` class too, that could be the cause of breaking layout:

```
.ico{
    top:-12px;);
```

You should also consider using a background-color as fallback in case background gradient image is not loaded:

```
.ico{
background:#eee url(../img/bg-ico.png) repeat-x;
}
```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n23fh/3/

Comment: I did the same procedure but still in google chrome, even with the new css and html in the new rules, and as it were a problem in google chrome because 40% of the time I give f5 on the page is correct? 
and 60% is incorrect, no solution yet.